# How can I add a comma to separate each group of three digits in a text input field?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, number-formatting

I have a text input field for a form where users are meant to enter a number. I would like to automatically insert a comma after every third digit.

For example, entering '20' would result in '20'. Entering '100' would result in '100'. But if they were to enter '1000', a comma would be inserted between the 1 and the following 0's (e.g., 1,000). Obviously this behaviour would continue should the number reach 7 digits (e.g., 1,000,000).

Is there an easy way to do this? I'm a bit of a newb at all of this, so please answer like you're talking to a child :)

Comment: The fastest way is `number.toLocaleString("en");`

Answer (score 11):

The following javascript:

```
function format(input)
{
    var nStr = input.value + '';
    nStr = nStr.replace( /\,/g, "");
    var x = nStr.split( '.' );
    var x1 = x[0];
    var x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while ( rgx.test(x1) ) {
        x1 = x1.replace( rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2' );
    }
    input.value = x1 + x2;
}
```

and the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="format(this)">
```

should solve your problem. The key is to use 'onkeyup'.

Try it here http://jsfiddle.net/YUSph/

Comment: Does not work when you need to edit in the middle -- cursor jumps to the end after replacing the input value.

Answer (score 4):

for the fun of it:

```js
'9876543210'
    .split('') // flip the entire string so that we can break every
    .reverse() //   3rd digit, starting from the end
    .join('')
    .split(/(...)/) // split on every 3rd
    .reverse()      // flip the string again, though now each group of 3 is
    .join(',')      //   backwards
    .replace(/,(?=,)|,$|^,/g, '') // remove extra ,
    .replace(/(,|^)(\d)(\d)?(\d)?/g, '$1$4$3$2') // flip each group of digits
// 9,876,543,210
```

Anyone want to take a stab at making that better?

Comment: Simpler: `"1234567".split('').reverse().join('').replace(/(.{3})/g,'$1,').replace(/,$/,'').split('').reverse().join('')`

Answer (score 1):

```
function addCommas(nStr){
        nStr += '';
        x = nStr.split('.');
        x1 = x[0];
        x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
        var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
        while (rgx.test(x1)) {
            x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
        return x1 + x2;
}
```

Pass the value of the input into function and set the input with the result returned.  You can bind this to an onchange event.

Here is a working example that relies on jquery to bind the change event and set the value: http://jsfiddle.net/TYyfn/

Comma script is from: http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic.html

Comment: That looks like what I want but I'm not to up on my javascript! Do I just create a new js file with that in it? How do I bind it to an onchange event? Sorry for being a dumb blonde

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's not terribly difficult.  I believe [this](http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic.html) reference may give you what you need.

Note that for this to be dynamic (as they type) you'd need to have this wired to the input field change handler.  Otherwise, you can wire this to the input field blur handler (which will have the effect of putting the commas in the field when they leave the field).

Comment: Hey there, I like the idea of it working as they type. The example from kmb385 is nice but must be blur (whatever that is) because it only works after you click out of the field. Can you give me a little more detail on how I go about making this work. I've really no idea about javascript other than including scripts someone has given me in a tutorial which is very much aimed at the total beginner. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function addCommas(nStr){
    var offset = nStr.length % 3;
    if (offset == 0)
        return nStr.substring(0, offset) + nStr.substring(offset).replace(/([0-9]{3})(?=[0-9]+)/g, "$1,");
    else
        return nStr.substring(0, offset) + nStr.substring(offset).replace(/([0-9]{3})/g, ",$1");
}


alert(addCommas("1234567"));
```

Comment: This answer looks nice and small (and therefore less daunting for me). But I haven't a clue what to do with it :(

Comment: This doesn't work... I get '123,456,7' when it should be '1,234,567'

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try: it may need  a little tweeking.

1. take the function from above:  function addCommas(nStr){...} and put in a js file.
2. add a script link in the page header to jquery library with:
   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"
3. be sure your text box has a unique id. ex: id="comma_input".
4. in the same js file add

   ```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#comma_input').keyup(function(){
            $(this).attr('value',addCommas($(this).attr('value')));
        });
    });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use standart JavaScript functions. Example here;
http://jsfiddle.net/azur/jD5pa/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>pure js solution</title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function digitGroup(dInput) {
                var output = "";
                try {
                    dInput = dInput.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""); // remove all chars including spaces, except digits.
                    var totalSize = dInput.length;
                    for (var i = totalSize - 1; i > -1; i--) {
                        output = dInput.charAt(i) + output;
                        var cnt = totalSize - i;
                        if (cnt % 3 === 0 && i !== 0) {
                            output = " " + output; // seperator is " "
                        }
                    }
                } catch (err)
                {
                    output = dInput; // it won't happen, but it's sweet to catch exceptions.
                }
                return output;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" value="53" onkeyup="this.value = digitGroup(this.value);">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please mention that your solution requires jQuery

Comment: Thank you for reminder, I've removed library requirement. The solution is now pure js.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, no RegEx, just array manipulation:

```
function decimalMark(s) {
    for (var a = s.split("").reverse(), b = [], i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { 
        if (i && i%3 === 0)
            b.unshift(",");
        b.unshift(a[i]);
    }

    return b.join("");
}
```

Be sure to pass a string to the function

```
decimalMark("1234")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple string solution in **pure JS**:

```
function addCommas(e) {
    var tgt = e.target, val = tgt.value.replace(/,/g, ''),
        amt = Math.ceil(val.length/3), newStr = '', x = 0; 
    while ( x <= amt ) {
        newStr += val.slice(x*3,(x+1)*3);
        newStr += ( x < amt-1 ) ? ',' : '';
        x++
    }
    tgt.value = newStr;
}
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('change', addCommas, false);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/TYyfn/141/

Answer (score 0):

```
var formatNumber = function(num, type) {
    var numSplit, int, dec, type;

    num = Math.abs(num);
    num = num.toFixed(2);

    numSplit = num.split('.')

    int = numSplit[0];
    if (int.length >= 3) {
        int = int.substr(0, int.length - 3) + ',' + int.substr(int.length - 3, 3);
    }

    dec = numSplit[1];

    return (type === 'exp'? sign = '-' : '+') + ' ' + int + '.' + dec;
};
```