# Add commas or spaces to group every three digits

Tags: javascript, string-formatting

I have a function to add commas to numbers:

```
function commafy( num ) {
  num.toString().replace( /\B(?=(?:\d{3})+)$/g, "," );
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't like decimals very well. Given the following usage examples, what is the best way to extend my function?

```
commafy( "123" )                 // "123"
commafy( "1234" )                // "1234"
                                 // Don't add commas until 5 integer digits
commafy( "12345" )               // "12,345"
commafy( "1234567" )             // "1,234,567"
commafy( "12345.2" )             // "12,345.2"
commafy( "12345.6789" )          // "12,345.6789"
                                 // Again, nothing until 5
commafy( ".123456" )             // ".123 456"
                                 // Group with spaces (no leading digit)
commafy( "12345.6789012345678" ) // "12,345.678 901 234 567 8"
```

Presumably the easiest way is to first split on the decimal point (if there is one). Where best to go from there?

Comment: Similar question & answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614268/how-can-i-add-a-comma-to-separate-each-group-of-three-digits-in-a-text-input-fie/24261626#24261626

Comment: Is there a way to make the output format in FORTRAN like this, without writing any new functions ?

Comment: Reminder that the Japanese like their numbers in groups of 4, while Indians prefer a final 3-group preceded by 2-groups. Gross oversimplification here, mind you.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Just split into two parts with '.' and format them individually.

```
function commafy( num ) {
    var str = num.toString().split('.');
    if (str[0].length >= 5) {
        str[0] = str[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,');
    }
    if (str[1] && str[1].length >= 5) {
        str[1] = str[1].replace(/(\d{3})/g, '$1 ');
    }
    return str.join('.');
}
```

Comment: I did a web service, based on that http://valjok.blogspot.com/2014/07/format-number-with-thouthands-separator.html

Answer (score 68):

Simple as that:

```
var theNumber = 3500;
theNumber.toLocaleString();
```

Comment: `toLocaleString()` cuts down the precision of the number to 3 decimal places on my machine.. this may not be what you want..

Comment: toLocaleString can use options. You may want to use "maximumFractionDigits" can be in a range of 1 - 21. To see the full description https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Answer (score 22):

Here are two concise ways I think maybe useful:

1. [Number.prototype.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

This method can convert a **number** to a string with a language-sensitive representation. It allows two parameters, which is `locales` & `options`. Those parameters may be a bit confusing, for more detail see that doc from MDN above.

In a word, you could simply use is as below:

```
console.log(
   Number(1234567890.12).toLocaleString()
)
// log -> "1,234,567,890.12"
```

*If you see different with me that because we ignore both two parameters and it will return a string base on your operation system.*

2. Use regex to match a string then replace to a new string.

   > Why we consider this? The `toLocaleString()` is a bit confusing and not all browser supported, also `toLocaleString()` will round the decimal, so we can do it in another way.

```
// The steps we follow are:
// 1. Converts a number(integer) to a string.
// 2. Reverses the string.
// 3. Replace the reversed string to a new string with the Regex
// 4. Reverses the new string to get what we want.

// This method is use to reverse a string.
function reverseString(str) { 
    return str.split("").reverse().join("");  
}

/**
 * @param {string | number} 
 */
function groupDigital(num) {
  const emptyStr = '';
  const group_regex = /\d{3}/g;

  // delete extra comma by regex replace.
  const trimComma = str => str.replace(/^[,]+|[,]+$/g, emptyStr)


  const str = num + emptyStr;
  const [integer, decimal] = str.split('.')

  const conversed = reverseString(integer);

  const grouped = trimComma(reverseString(
    conversed.replace(/\d{3}/g, match => `${match},`)
  ));

  return !decimal ? grouped : `${grouped}.${decimal}`;
}


console.log(groupDigital(1234567890.1234)) // 1,234,567,890.1234
console.log(groupDigital(123456))  // 123,456
console.log(groupDigital("12.000000001"))  // 12.000000001
```

Comment: Tips: 1. You can extend the second way to be more flexible and applicable.  2. To avoid truncated you should use string prefer than a number as input.

Answer (score 9):

Easiest way:

## 1

```
var num = 1234567890,
result = num.toLocaleString() ;// result will equal to "1 234 567 890"
```

## 2

```
var num = 1234567.890,
result = num.toLocaleString() + num.toString().slice(num.toString().indexOf('.')) // will equal to 1 234 567.890
```

## 3

```
var num = 1234567.890123,
result = Number(num.toFixed(0)).toLocaleString() + '.' + Number(num.toString().slice(num.toString().indexOf('.')+1)).toLocaleString()
//will equal to 1 234 567.890 123
```

## 4

If you want ',' instead of ' ':

```
var num = 1234567.890123,
result = Number(num.toFixed(0)).toLocaleString().split(/\s/).join(',') + '.' + Number(num.toString().slice(num.toString().indexOf('.')+1)).toLocaleString()
//will equal to 1,234,567.890 123
```

If not working, set the parameter like: "toLocaleString('ru-RU')"
parameter "en-EN", will split number by the ',' instead of ' '

All function used in my code are native JS functions. You'll find them in GOOGLE or in any JS Tutorial/Book

Comment: Please comment what are all the used functions do. Documentation links would also be useful

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy with the integer part (I haven't looked at it closly), then:

```
function formatDecimal(n) {
  n = n.split('.');
  return commafy(n[0]) + '.' + n[1];
}
```

Of course you may want to do some testing of *n* first to make sure it's ok, but that's the logic of it.

#### Edit

Ooops! missed the bit about spaces! You can use the same regular exprssion as commafy except with spaces instead of commas, then reverse the result.

Here's a function based on vol7ron's and not using reverse:

```
function formatNum(n) {
  var n = ('' + n).split('.');
  var num = n[0];
  var dec = n[1];
  var r, s, t;

  if (num.length > 3) {
    s = num.length % 3;

    if (s) {
      t = num.substring(0,s);
      num = t + num.substring(s).replace(/(\d{3})/g, ",$1");
    } else {
      num = num.substring(s).replace(/(\d{3})/g, ",$1").substring(1);
    }
  }

  if (dec && dec.length > 3) {
    dec = dec.replace(/(\d{3})/g, "$1 ");
  }

  return num + (dec? '.' + dec : '');
}
```

Comment: It's kind of awkward to reverse the string twice; would be nice to have a regex that works for the other way.

Comment: @Ben, you could loop through the string, but I think it would be faster to reverse twice.  a pure regex method would require lookbehind, which I don't think JavaScript/ECMAScript have added to standard.

Comment: @vol7ron - you can also use substring to get an even multiple of 3 to add commas to, then put the extra bit back on.

Comment: Not quite correct:  
formatNum(-1234) => "-1 234"  
formatNum(-12345) => " 12345"  
formatNum(-123456) => "- 123 456"

Comment: @Shrike—I didn't see no stinkin' negatives!! Easily accommodated by trimming the sign if there is one and putting it back on at the end. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I have extended #RobG's answer a bit more and made a sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2y9dsnnt/)

```
function formatNum(n, prec, currSign) {
    if(prec==null) prec=2;
  var n = ('' + parseFloat(n).toFixed(prec).toString()).split('.');
  var num = n[0];
  var dec = n[1];
  var r, s, t;

  if (num.length > 3) {
    s = num.length % 3;

    if (s) {
      t = num.substring(0,s);
      num = t + num.substring(s).replace(/(\d{3})/g, ",$1");
    } else {
      num = num.substring(s).replace(/(\d{3})/g, ",$1").substring(1);
    }
  }
    return (currSign == null ? "": currSign +" ") + num + (dec? '.' + dec : '');
}
alert(formatNum(123545.3434));
alert(formatNum(123545.3434,2));
alert(formatNum(123545.3434,2,'€'));
```

and extended same way the #Ghostoy's answer

```
function commafy( num, prec, currSign ) {
    if(prec==null) prec=2;
    var str = parseFloat(num).toFixed(prec).toString().split('.');
    if (str[0].length >= 5) {
        str[0] = str[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,');
    }
    if (str[1] && str[1].length >= 5) {
        str[1] = str[1].replace(/(\d{3})/g, '$1 ');
    }
    return (currSign == null ? "": currSign +" ") + str.join('.');
}

alert(commafy(123545.3434));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go edited after reading your comments.

```
function commafy( arg ) {
   arg += '';                                         // stringify
   var num = arg.split('.');                          // incase decimals
   if (typeof num[0] !== 'undefined'){
      var int = num[0];                               // integer part
      if (int.length > 4){
         int     = int.split('').reverse().join('');  // reverse
         int     = int.replace(/(\d{3})/g, "$1,");    // add commas
         int     = int.split('').reverse().join('');  // unreverse
      }
   }
   if (typeof num[1] !== 'undefined'){
      var dec = num[1];                               // float part
      if (dec.length > 4){
         dec     = dec.replace(/(\d{3})/g, "$1 ");    // add spaces
      }
   }

   return (typeof num[0] !== 'undefined'?int:'') 
        + (typeof num[1] !== 'undefined'?'.'+dec:'');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
function commafy(inVal){
   var arrWhole = inVal.split(".");
   var arrTheNumber = arrWhole[0].split("").reverse();
   var newNum = Array();
   for(var i=0; i<arrTheNumber.length; i++){
          newNum[newNum.length] = ((i%3===2) && (i<arrTheNumber.length-1)) ? "," + arrTheNumber[i]: arrTheNumber[i];
   }
   var returnNum = newNum.reverse().join("");
   if(arrWhole[1]){
          returnNum += "." + arrWhole[1];
   }
   return returnNum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this little function everywhere when searching for "adding commas to a number", and it works great for most cases. It didn't work for me because I was adding commas a dollar amount in a form, and wanted to do so after every keystroke. In my case it worked up to 9999, but once you get to five digits it would result in something like this - 1,4,000. By adding one line of code I was able to strip all commas prior to the function call after each keystroke like so:

```
    function addSomeCommas(number) {
      var parts = number.toString().split(".");
      parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
      return parts.join(".");
    }

    $("#dollarAmount").on("keyup change",function() {
      var num = $this).val();
      num = num.replaceAll(',', '');
      var commaNum = addSomeCommas(num);
      $(this).val(commaNum);
    });
```

Comment: Hey, this is perfect if only going to 4 digits. I'm up-voting this since it worked the way I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your usage examples are not representative of already-working code but instead desired behavior, and you are looking for help with the algorithm, I think you are already on the right track with splitting on any decimals.

Once split, apply the existing regex to the left side, a similiar regex adding the spaces instead of commas to the right, and then rejoin the the two into a single string before returning.

Unless, of course, there are other considerations or I have misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same as the solution from Ghostoy, but it fixes an issue where numbers in the thousands are not handled properly. Changed '5' to '4':

```
export function commafy(num) {
    const str = num.toString().split('.');
    if (str[0].length >= 4) {
        str[0] = str[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,');
    }
    if (str[1] && str[1].length >= 4) {
        str[1] = str[1].replace(/(\d{3})/g, '$1 ');
    }
    return str.join('.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Code in Java
private static String formatNumber(String myNum) {
    char[] str = myNum.toCharArray();
    int numCommas = str.length / 3;
    char[] formattedStr = new char[str.length + numCommas];

    for(int i = str.length - 1, j = formattedStr.length - 1, cnt = 0; i >= 0 && j >=0 ;) {
        if(cnt != 0 && cnt % 3 == 0 && j > 0) {
            formattedStr[j] = ',';
            j--;
        }

        formattedStr[j] = str[i];
        i--;
        j--;
        cnt++;
    }
    return String.valueOf(formattedStr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it mathematically, depending on how many digits you want to separate, you can start from one digit with 10 to 100 for 2, and so on.

```
function splitDigits(num) {
    num=Math.ceil(num);
    let newNum = '';
    while (num > 1000){
      let remain = num % 1000;
      num = Math.floor(num / 1000);
      newNum = remain + ',' + newNum;
    }
    return num + ',' + newNum.slice(0,newNum.length-1);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you should select the input with  `querySelector` like:

```
let field = document.querySelector("input");
```

and then

```
        field.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
            for (let i = 1 ; i <= field.value.length; i++) {
                field.value = field.value.replace(",", "");
            }
            let counter=0;

            for (let i = 1 ; i <= field.value.length; i++) {
                if ( i  % ((3 * (counter+1) ) + counter) ===0){
                    let tempVal =field.value
                    field.value = addStr(tempVal,field.value.length - i,",")
                    counter++;
                    console.log(field.value);
                }
            }
            // field.value = parseInt(field.value.replace(/\D/g, ''), 10);
            // var n = parseInt(e.target.value.replace(/\D/g,''),10);
            // e.target.value = n.toLocaleString();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

#### If you want always 2 digits

With `ES2017` padEnd and `ES2015` destructering.

```
function formatAmount(num: number): string {
  const [int, fra] = num.toString().split('.');
  return Number(int).toLocaleString() + '.' + (fra ?? '').padEnd(2, '0');
}
```

it will add spaces or commas before `.` in dependence on your browser language and add 2 digits at the end.