# Formatting number in European format with two decimals

Tags: javascript, formatting, locale, culture

Trying to format a number to two decimals format in European culture. So that comma is decimal separator and space thousands separator.

In example **213245** should be formatted as **213 245,00**

How can I do that?

```
213245.toFixed(2).toLocaleString();
```

gives **213245.00** but it should be **213 245,00**

however

```
213245.toLocaleString()
```

gives **213 245**

Fiddling below:

```
var out, input;
input = 213245;

// TEST 1
out = input.toFixed(2);   
console.log(out); // 213245.00
out = out.toLocaleString();
console.log(out); // 213245.00

// TEST 2
out = input.toLocaleString();
console.log(out); // 213 245
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rootnode/8p2vad8u/7/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784894/add-commas-or-spaces-to-group-every-three-digits

Comment: Are you sure that your locale is set correctly?

Comment: If you consider 213245.toFixed(2).toLocaleString();  as a string you can use replace() function to replace '.' with ','

Comment: Beware that [Number.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) produces a string thus you're using [Object.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toLocaleString) rather than [Number.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) -- *Side note: it's for statements like this that Brits want to leave Europe...*

Comment: @AlvaroG.Vicario _Side note: what? I don't want to start politically here, but you are seriously conflating things. The OP meant in comparison the American notation, which the Brits happened to adopt_

Comment: @somethinghere Come on, do I really need to add an smiley to every single tongue-in-cheek sentence I say on the internet?

Comment: @AlvaroG.Vicario _Sorry about that! I guess it's a politically-sensitive topic :)_ Now, back to the question: theres actually a useful implementation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript - this one is for formatting money, but it works for decimals as well.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

When you use [Number.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) you obtain a **string** (not a number any more). For that reason, subsequent calls to `.toLocaleString()` launch the generic [Object.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toLocaleString) method that knows nothing about numbers, instead of the [Number.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) you want.

Having a look at the documentation we can compose something like this:

```
> Number(213245).toLocaleString("es-ES", {minimumFractionDigits: 2});
"213.245,00"
```

```js
console.log(Number(213245).toLocaleString("es-ES", {minimumFractionDigits: 2}));
```

This is a *relatively* new addition so make sure to verify [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Browser_compatibility), but it's been working in Firefox and Chrome-like browsers for a few years now. In particular, some runtimes like [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/intl.html#intl_internationalization_support) do not include the full ICU dataset by default.