# JavaScript - easy way to format something to currency w/out decimals

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to come up with a way without using someone's plugin to format a number with decimals to currency without decimals. I have found the below to be the easiest way thus far:

```
yourVar.toLocaleString("en", { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }).split('.')[0]
```

example:

```
before:446882086.00

after:$446,882,086
```

Answer (score 0):

With help from this question :[Add commas or spaces to group every three digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784894/add-commas-or-spaces-to-group-every-three-digits)

I have created this function :

```
function convertString(currency, input) {
  var thisInt = Math.round(input); //this removes numbers after decimal   
  var thisOutputValue = currency + commafy(thisInt); //add currency symbol and commas

  return thisOutputValue;
}


function commafy(num) {
  var str = num.toString().split('.');
  if (str[0].length >= 5) {
    str[0] = str[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,');
  }
  if (str[1] && str[1].length >= 5) {
    str[1] = str[1].replace(/(\d{3})/g, '$1 ');
  }
  return str.join('.');
}    

var changeIntToCurrencyString = convertString('$', 435345.00) //change numbers into dollars

console.log(changeIntToCurrencyString )
```

The above code converts the integer `435345.00` to dollar currency string : `$435,345`. It should work for all other integer values :)

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/zL817x5a/3/

```js
function convertString(currency, input) {
  var thisInt = Math.round(input); //this removes numbers after decimal   
  var thisOutputValue = currency + commafy(thisInt); //add currency symbol and commas

  return thisOutputValue;
}


function commafy(num) {
  var str = num.toString().split('.');
  if (str[0].length >= 5) {
    str[0] = str[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,');
  }
  if (str[1] && str[1].length >= 5) {
    str[1] = str[1].replace(/(\d{3})/g, '$1 ');
  }
  return str.join('.');
}

var tryoutint = 435345.00;
var changeIntToCurrencyString = convertString('$', tryoutint) //change numbers into dollars

console.log(changeIntToCurrencyString)
alert(tryoutint + ' : ' + changeIntToCurrencyString)
```