# Currency input for AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, format

I'm trying to make input for currency where thousand are separate with "." and decimal are separate with "," example: 1.000,00. And that is how it should be displayed in input field but model should be like 1000.00. If we have model value it should be displayed as 1.000,00,and if there are not it could stay empty So far I have something  like this:

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.amount = 12548.12

});
app.directive('smartFloat', function () {
     return {
            controller($scope) {

            },
            require: 'ngModel',
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
                function inputValue() {
                    var inputVal = element.val();
                    var res;
                    

                    //clearing left side zeros
                    while (inputVal.charAt(0) == '0') {
                        inputVal = inputVal.substr(1);
                    }

                    inputVal = inputVal.replace(/[^\d.\',']/g, '');

                    var point = inputVal.indexOf(",");
                    if (point >= 0) {
                        inputVal = inputVal.slice(0, point + 3);
                    }

                    var decimalSplit = inputVal.split(",");
                    var intPart = decimalSplit[0];
                    var decPart = decimalSplit[1];

                    intPart = intPart.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
                    if (intPart.length > 3) {
                        var intDiv = Math.floor(intPart.length / 3);
                        while (intDiv > 0) {
                            var lastComma = intPart.indexOf(".");
                            if (lastComma < 0) {
                                lastComma = intPart.length;
                            }

                            if (lastComma - 3 > 0) {
                                intPart = intPart.slice(0, lastComma - 3) + "." + intPart.slice(lastComma - 3);
                            }
                            intDiv--;
                        }
                    }

                    if (decPart === undefined) {
                        decPart = "";
                    }
                    else {
                        decPart = "," + decPart;
                    }
                    if (intPart == "" && decPart != "") {
                        intPart = 0;
                    }
                    if (intPart == "" && decPart == "") {
                        res = null;
                    } else {
                        res = intPart + decPart;
                    }

                    if (res != inputValue) {
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(res);
                        ngModel.$render();

                    }
                    return res

                }
                    //from model to view  
                    ngModel.$parsers.push(inputValue);


                ngModel.$formatters.push(function(val){
                  return val
                });



            }
        };

    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.6.1" data-semver="1.6.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="myController">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAmount" name="inputAmount" placeholder="Amount" ng-model="amount" smart-float />

            <span class="help-block" ng-show="myForm.inputAmount.$error.float">
                Invalid Amount!
            </span>
    {{amount}}
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: So you're trying to directly **swap** decimal and comma values? Why not simply use a value like `10,000.00`? And considering it's a direct swap, you'll probably need to use a third value as an intermediary. What does your script currently return, and what part **specifically** are you having trouble with?

Comment: In some countries currency are formatted in this way 1.000,00. Script currently return what is in input field.The problem is that I need format on model in 1000.00 way and in input 1.000,00 .And  input field  allow only numbers and comma inputs

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6786040/2195742) and adapted:

```js
function commafy( num ) {
    var str = num.split('.');
    if (str[0].length >= 2) {
        str[0] = str[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1.');
    }

    return str.join(',');
}

console.log(commafy('1000.00'));
console.log(commafy('1230154.27'));
```

Then you simply need to use this function to render your number, but keep in your model the real `1000.00` or `1230154.27`.

Good luck