# Display comma separated Number using locale string method in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to display the numbers with comma separated like 120,456.02

I tried the below method using js and it worked fine. But in apps scripts, it throws illegal radix exception

```
function toDec(n) {
    //return parseFloat(Math.round(n * 100) / 100).toFixed(2) + ' '; will display without comma
    return Number(parseFloat(Math.round(n * 100) / 100)).toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 2});
}
```

Any workaround available?

Comment: Is the value being printed to a Google Sheet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In GAS `toLocaleString` is just an alias for `toString`, and is therefore useless. ([Relevant bug tracker item](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32937) from Rhino, on which GAS runs.)

So, we have to do some manual comma insertion following [Add commas or spaces to group every three digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784894/add-commas-or-spaces-to-group-every-three-digits):

```
var n = 123456.789;
var str = n.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,');
```

where `str` is now `123,456.79`.