# What options are available to localeCompare in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Anybody know what options are available?

Chrome console allows the [standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) options:

```
'ä'.localeCompare('z', 'de'); // -1
'ä'.localeCompare('z', 'sv'); // 1
```

Google Apps Script appears to ignore:

```
'ä'.localeCompare('z', 'de'); // -1
'ä'.localeCompare('z', 'sv'); // -1
```

Other options are similarly unavailable:

```
// in German, ä has a as the base letter
'ä'.localeCompare('a', 'de', { sensitivity: 'base' });
// -> 0 in chrome,
// -> 1 in GAS

// in Swedish, ä and a are separate base letters
'ä'.localeCompare('a', 'sv', { sensitivity: 'base' });
// -> 1 in chrome
// -> 1 in GAS
```

Does it have anything to do with active user's locale? Or does GAS just have a stripped-down version of localeCompare? Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Apps Script is based on JavaScript 1.6.

Comment: Related: [Is there a complete definition of the Google App Script Syntax somewhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12279357/1595451)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does GAS just have a stripped-down version of localeCompare

Yes, it does. It runs on Rhino (a JS implementation in Java), in which `localeCompare` ignores all arguments after the first one.  For example,

```
"a".localeCompare("b", "c", "d")
```

is obviously invalid in ECMAScript but runs in GAS, with the arguments "c" and "d" being silently ignored.

This is somewhat similar to the situation with `toLocaleString` which [acts as toString](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50962680).